# grails addTo entering duplicate data for hasMany relationship

Tags: grails, groovy, has-many

I have a pretty simple hasMany relationship where a "product" hasMany "packages".  I'm running a script to try and fill in the data, which works fine on the first run.  However on the second run, it starts inputing duplicates, which I though was not possible for a hasMany

```
package = Package.findBySourceId(packageId) ?: new Package(name:packageName, price:packagePrice, sourceId:packageId).save(flush:true)

product = Product.findBySourceId(productId)                 
product.addToPackages(package)
product.save(flush:true)
```

When I put on sql logging on, I can see that sometimes the select that should run on the addToPackages call is not run.  It just does the select to find the product and then a straight insert into the join table.

I don't want to add the exact queries because of work but basically its like

```
Select -> for the initial package which it finds

Select -> for product which it finds by the product id

Insert -> insert into the join table without even a select to check if an entry exists
```

However sometimes instead of that insert it will run a select and find the match and the process will start over.  No idea on the logic going on behind grails here.  Keep in mind, I have a script running that's pulling the data with thousands of line, is this a session issue somehow?

Comment: What does your Package class look like?  Do you have the correct constraints set on the sourceId property?

Comment: Sounds like you have some sort of non-deterministic behaviour going on. uck...

Answer (score 3):

Have you used a List or Set for your collection on the "many" side of your one-to-many?  The default is a Set, which should constrain against duplicates.  If you've mapped the collection using a List, then you may have created the problem.

Alternatively, verify that the identity property "package" has the correct behaviors for equals() and hashCode().

Comment: how would you map the collection to use a list instead of a set?

Comment: @MartinKlosi Just declare `List myObjects` before `static hasMany = [myObjects: MyObject]`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520187/defining-default-sort-order-in-grails-gorm for an example.

Answer (score 0):

See
[Domain hasMany association using a List is adding duplicate items when the parent is saved](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/4446)